# Как заставить рисовать хром "серую" иконку у расширения?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Мне нужно, чтобы иконка расширения при определенных условиях становилась "серой". Ни как не могу найти способ заставить хром рисовать такую иконку.

Важный момент - "серые" иконки - это именно фича хрома. Т.е. вариант с заготоволенными иконками с нормальными и серыми цветами меня не интересует.

Comment: Отключите расширение, и тогда иконка посереет. По моему, вариант с заготоволенными иконками с нормальными и серыми цветами - единственный, вам же нужна серая иконка у работающего расширения. Вот [тут](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/tree/master/shells/chrome/icons) или [тут](https://github.com/adblockplus/adblockpluschrome/tree/master/icons) ребята сами себе серые иконки сделали

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29946401/why-is-this-chrome-browseraction-seticon-method-not-working#answer-29947496 можно менять иконку из кода

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Стоит пойти от обратного: почему иконка у вас "цветная"? Полагаю вы используете [page_action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction), иконка которого всегда цветная/оригинальная.

То, что вас интересует - это [browser_action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction). Данное API позволяет поместить иконку приложения, которая по-умолчанию не активирована для каждого таба (и имеет серый цвет).